# How to show Collectionview cells near to each cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

**I need cells one nearby another like below**

[image]

**but i am getting like this**: in short phones they are very far from one another

[image]

for collectionview i have given constraints like this in stroryboard:

```
height = 80, leading = trailing = 0, top = 20
```

and in viewdidload:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //services collectionview cell
    let serviceLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    serviceLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    serviceLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    serviceLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    self.servicesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = serviceLayout
    servicesCollectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    servicesCollectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
   }
```

i haven't given anything more then this.. please do help.. to get collectionview cells to come near to each cell

**EDIT:**

for `servicesCollectionView` i have comment everything in the didload and added like this.. then its working

```
servicesCollectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

for this cell i need to show near to each other, how to do that.. plz do suggest

```
galleryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = LeftAlignCellCollectionFlowLayout()

    let galleryLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    galleryLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    self.galleryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = galleryLayout
    self.galleryCollectionView!.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom:0, right: 0)
    let heightGallery = 120
    let widthGallery = view.frame.size.width
    if let galleryLayout = self.galleryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        galleryLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        galleryLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        galleryLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: widthGallery * 0.7, height: CGFloat(heightGallery))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to get this behavior.

```
import UIKit

class LeftAlignCellCollectionFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    private(set) var cellHeight: CGFloat = 36
    init(cellHeight: CGFloat) {
        super.init()
        self.cellHeight = cellHeight
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return nil }
        
        self.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2
        
        var newAttributes = attributes
        var leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
        var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0
        
        let availableWidth: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout
        
        for attribute in attributes {
            if let cellAttribute = layout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: attribute.indexPath) {
                if cellAttribute.frame.width > availableWidth {
                    cellAttribute.frame.origin.x = 0
                    cellAttribute.frame.size = CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: cellHeight)
                }
                else {
                    if cellAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {
                        leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
                    }
                    
                    var frame = cellAttribute.frame
                    frame.origin.x = leftMargin
                    frame.size.height = cellHeight
                    cellAttribute.frame = frame
                    
                    leftMargin += cellAttribute.frame.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing
                    maxY = max(cellAttribute.frame.maxY , maxY)
                }
                
                newAttributes.append(cellAttribute)
            }
        }
        
        return newAttributes
    }
}
```

Here's how you use it.

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = LeftAlignCellCollectionFlowLayout(cellHeight: 40)
```

Comment: i need this kind of feature for two collectionviews

Comment: can we do like this in storyboard constraints? without using above code bcz i am working with constraints

Comment: Everything you have done in storyboard, collectionView / collectionViewCell etc. will remain the same. Do not change anything in the storyboard, Create `@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!` inside your code, connect your collectionView from storyboard to this variable and then write the above line `collectionView.collectionViewLayout = .....`.

Comment: i want this for two collectionview with different heights.. but u have given like this `private let cellHeight: CGFloat = 50` then how to use this for both collectionview

Comment: i have edited the post.. where i need solution.. can u help me

Comment: I have updated the post to make this cellHeight configurable, now you can supply a cellHeight value while initializing the flow layout instance. In the question update  you are setting `galleryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout` two times, first time you set it to correct layout subclass, then you set it to some other instance of standard UICollectionViewFlowLayout class. You can assign all the properties (that you are configuring the standard layout instance with) to the LeftAlign.... subclass instance as well. You need to work with one layout instance at a time.